# Dovecot: userdb lookup: connect(/var/run/dovecot/auth-master) failed: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, mail-server, dovecot

i have a strange problem with dovecot, since a day i get this error:

```
Error: userdb lookup: connect(/var/run/dovecot/auth-master) failed: Permission denied (euid=7788(email) egid=7788(email) UNIX perms appear ok (ACL/MAC wrong?), dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
```

Permissions are these:

```
srw-rw----  1 email   email      0 Jun  3 16:25 auth-master
```

relevant part of dovecot.conf:

```
socket listen {
        master {
            path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
            mode = 0660
            user = email
            group = email
        }
        client {
            path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
            mode = 0660
            user = postfix
            group = postfix
        }
    }
}


listen = *
```

I don't really have any idea what is causing the error... Changing permissions doesn't seem to fix it.

Any suggestions?

Best regards 
cptflint

Comment: Anybody an idea...?